# Get set navigation left Button swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to Get or set function use for navigation left button but i am really confused because i am set image but they give me nil value output how to solve this is my code for set or get navigation button:

```
var leftNavigationItem: UIImage? {
    get {
        return nil
    }
    set {
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        print(leftNavigationItem)  // output = nil
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: newValue, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.leftNavigationItemAction(_:)))
    }
}
```

i am use this code in viewdidload:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Sign In"
    setUI()
    usernameTF.becomeFirstResponder()
    leftNavigationItem = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "back")
}
```

Comment: `#imageLiteral(resourceName: "back")` returns nil ?

Comment: Yes return nil value

Comment: Check 'back' image is exist in Assets or not

Comment: yes this image exist in Assets

Comment: Then your issue is with `#imageLiteral(resourceName: "back")`, nothing to do with `UINavigationController` nor `UIBarButtonItem` (at least for now).

Comment: How to Solve ??????

Comment: I am trying to change with another one  image  but always give me same nil value......

Comment: remove the get clause

Comment: Try with leftNavigationItem = UIImage(named: "back.png")

Comment: @Woodstock then how to get or set image ????

Comment: get with self.leftNavigationItem

Comment: @Sateesh always give me nil value sir.....

Comment: @Woodstock no output sir
return nil value.....

Comment: Try to remove 'back.png' from Assets and added it again. make sure its in png format

Comment: Yes @Sateesh this is png format.

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly returning `nil`, what do you expect?

Change this:

```
var leftNavigationItem: UIImage? {
    get {
        return nil
    }
    set {
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        print(leftNavigationItem)  // output = nil
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: newValue, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.leftNavigationItemAction(_:)))
    }
}
```

to this:

```
var leftNavigationItem: UIImage? {
    set {
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        print(leftNavigationItem)  // output = nil
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: newValue, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.leftNavigationItemAction(_:)))
    }
}
```

Your code is madness.

When you want to 'get' your image just access through `self.leftNavigationItem`.

Comment: Give me error :
Variable with a setter must also have a getter

Comment: Just add the missing getter: `return self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.image`

Comment: Then the problem is related to the image Asset as stated in the question's comments.